# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have an automation script that needs to be executed through Jenkins. For this I need to open Firefox browser. For this I made some R&D and installed certain plugins in Jenkins like, ChromeDriver, XVFB and XVNC plugins.

I've added the "Xvfb installation" details in Jenkins global tool configuration and configured my Project with enabling the "Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after." option in Build Environment.

After these setup I executed the build, but when executed, this error showed up

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

So for fixing the above, I made some R&D and came across this

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit
```

When I enter the above code in Terminal, it just opens a new document in gedit.

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY gedit
```

Now I'm stuck where to set the above variables. In which file should I update this?

If I fix this issue will the Jenkins build will be successful?

The project I have is a maven project, which when executed through eclipse, works fine by opening the browser. But through Jenkins it is failing.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please help. Thanks in advance.